# How can I allow connections from 127.0.0.1 (localhost) on ports from 49152 to 65535 using firewall-cmd?

Tags: rhel, firewalld

How can I allow connections from 127.0.0.1 (localhost) on ports from 49152 to 65535 using firewall-cmd?

This is needed to deploy a jupyterlab server on RHEL8.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best,
Benoit

Comment: ... why would you block anything from localhost in the first place?

Comment: If you're using firewall-cmd `lo` should be unblocked by default. Nothing is needed.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to do by editing /etc/sysconfig/iptables. You would need to add these two lines.

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 49152:65535 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 49152:65535 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome click on right answer if your problem is solved